# $L^\infty$ is complete.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to understand the following proof that $L^\infty$ is complete.

$L^\infty$ is a vector space of measurable functions $f \colon X \to [0,\infty]$ with the norm being given by $\text{inf} \{ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \colon \mu(f^{-1}( (\alpha, \infty])) = 0 \}$.

To prove that $L^\infty$ is complete, we let $\{f_n\}$ be Cauchy in $L^\infty$.

We set $A_k = \{ x \in X \colon \left|f_k(x) \right| > \left|f_k \right|_{L^\infty} \}$.

And we set $B_{m,n} = \{ x \in X \colon \left|f_n(x) - f_m(x) \right| > \left|f_n - f_m\right|_{L^\infty} \}$

By definition, measure of $A_k$ and $B_{m,n}$ is 0, so let $E$ be the union of all $A_k$s and $B_{m,n}s$. Then $E$ has measure 0 as it is countable union of measure $0$ sets.

Now, the proof says on $E^c$, $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy and therefore have a uniform point-wise limit $f(x)$. This is the part I don't understand.

So on $E^c$, we know that $\left|f_n(x) \right| < \left|f_n \right|_{L^\infty}$ for all $n$ and $\left|f_n(x) - f_m(x) \right| < \left| f_n - f_m \right|_{L^\infty}$ for all $n$ and $m$.

But why does this imply that $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy on $E^c$?

I'm thinking it's along the line of $\left|f_n - f_m \right|$ being bounded above by $\left| f_n - f_m \right|_{L^\infty}$, which we can bound since $f_n$ is Cauchy, but I'm not sure on the details.

Thanks!

Comment: "Uniformly Cauchy on $E^c$" requires $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<a_{n,m}$ for $x \in E^c$, where $a_{n,m}$ does not depend on $x$ and has the property $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \exists N \, \forall n,m \geq N \, a_{n,m} < \varepsilon$. You have this bound with $a_{n,m}=\| f_n - f_m \|_{L^\infty}$.

Comment: @Ian what was the use of $A_k$ here?

Comment: It wasn't really needed at all; all you really needed to do was to cut out the places where the $f_n$ are actually infinite (to avoid subtraction being ill-defined).

Answer (score 2):

You can go another way and see that $L^{\infty} = (L^1)^*$ and every dual space of normed space is complete.